# Find if a number lies in this pattern

Tags: algorithms, pattern-recognition

I have a sequence of numbers below...

$1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16 ...$

You get this list by starting at $1$ then add $1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...$

Given a number $n$, how can I determine if it will show up in this pattern of numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $k$th term in your sequence is $1+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$. [See [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).] Given your number $n$, you just need to check if it is of this form or not.

Comment: Just to note (not necessarily for angryavian): the true triangular numbers start at $0$. Thus, this is more of a triangular sequence rather than the triangular numbers. Same idea of course, as mentioned above.

Comment: I have no idea how you got that but it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Put another way, take your number, multiply by $8,$ then subtract $7.$ If the result is a perfect square, the number is in the sequence, otherwise no.

Comment: Analogous to that, for just $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ you can multiply by $8$ and add $1$. If that result is a perfect square, it is in the sequence.

Comment: @Vincent, the given sequence is shifted by a constant, it would be $(n^2 +n+2)/2$

Comment: Yes. I was using your same technique but applied it to the triangular numbers. I thought since this question is very closely related to the triangular numbers is was worth mentioning the application of your method to them.

Comment: @Vincent, I see.

Comment: @Vincent, alright, homework. If you can completely factor a positive integer $n,$ how can you tell whether there is an expression in integers (not necessarily positive) $n = x^2 + x y + 2 y^2?$

Comment: Hmmm. Is what I said above incorrect? And therefore, answering your question will show me why?

Comment: @Vincent, you got it right. The two-variable problem i suggest is quite different; if you don't have time, you don't. But if you take $|x|,|y|$ up to some bound like 1000, then take all values of $x^2 + x y + 2 y^2$ up to 1000 and factor those, there is a pattern.

Comment: Side note before I check out what you asked. For the triangular numbers, after multiplying by $8$ and adding $1$ then checking if your result is a perfect square. If you take the square root of that result to get that perfect square, subtracting $1$ and then dividing by $2$ will give you the position of the number in the sequence. I.e. We know $153$ is the $17^{th}$ triangular number. $153\cdot 8=1224 \to 1224+1=1225 = 35^2 \to 35-1=34 \to 34/2 = 17$.

It may not be that interesting, but I was happy to have noticed it just now.

Comment: @Vincent, good.

Comment: @Vincent To describe what you have observed, $$8 \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1=4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @WillJagy I looked at it as: $(x,y):(0,0)(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)...$ 
Giving: $0,4,16,36,64,100,...$ 
Which is: $0^2, 2^2, 4^2, 6^2,...$ 
Thus, $x^2+xy+2y^2$ will yield $(2m)^2$ where $m \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Vincent, thanks for looking at it. The idea is to have $x,y$ vary independently. I think I'd better tell you, the numbers $n = x^2 + x y + 2 y^2$ in integers have, in their prime factorization, even exponents on all primes $q$ of the form $7w + 3$ or $7 w + 5$ or $7w + 6.$

Comment: Yah, I would have never got that. Hah.